# How to return a boolean value from a Java class to ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring

I want to return a `boolean` value from my Java class to the Ajax request. The value is successfully passed from the ajax to the java method but can't return a `boolean` value back to Ajax. I am getting an error: `unknown return value type`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/availability", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean emailAvailability(String email) {
    boolean a = true;
    Query q = new Query("UserDetailsNew");
    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);

    System.out.println("email in availability : " + email);

    for (Entity e : pq.asIterable()) {
        String Email = (String) e.getProperty("Email");
        if (Email.equals(email)) {
            a = false;
            return a;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

My Ajax Code :

```
var email = $("#email").val();
    $.ajax({
          method:"post",
          url:"/availability",
          dataType: 'JSON',
          data:{ email: JSON.stringify(email) },
          success : function (data){
          console.log(data);
          if(!data){
              $("#email").focusout(function(){
                    $('#submit').prop('disabled',true);
                    $('.status').html("Email already taken...");
                });
          }
          else {
              $('.status').html("Email Available...");
              $('#submit').prop('disabled',false);
          }
         } 
    });
```

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace? It looks like an error in your Java code, possibly related to Spring-MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use the the JsonResponse class for doing this.Here the @ResponseBody annotation takes care of the result type.Please refer the docs for more info.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/availability", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse emailAvailability(String email) {
    JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();
    boolean a = true;
    Query q = new Query("UserDetailsNew");
    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);

    System.out.println("email in availability : " + email);

    for (Entity e : pq.asIterable()) {
        String Email = (String) e.getProperty("Email");
        if (Email.equals(email)) {
            a = false;
            return a;
        }
    }
     res.setStatus("success");
     res.setResult(a);
     return res;

}
```

In the ajax you can verify this using

```
success: function(response){
            // we have the response
       if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
//your code
}
```

Please try this once.Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still I get a 406 (Not Acceptable) error in my console... Is there a problem with the dataType="JSON"??? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @ShiyaamSundar try adding these two parms to your ajax once     datatype : "json",                                         contentType: "application/json"

Comment: Still the same error... The ajax s passing the right values, I am printing out the values in the loop to check the validity, everything is running perfectly but creating problem while returning the value...

Answer (score 0):

This should return JSON data. The following is my demo:

```
public void validateCode_add(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,ModelMap model){
    boolean flag = true;
    String code=request.getParameter("code");
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(code)) {
        XgInstructorCheckProject entity = this.manager.findByCode(code);
        if (entity != null) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    ResponseUtils.renderJson(response, flag + "");
}
```